# Reach an oracle form application from another pc

Tags: oracle, web, oracleforms

I have been searching for hours to find a way, i can reach my oracle form application 9i (placed in my virtual machine XP )from another computer. I add these lines in formsweb.cfg file

```
[Test]
form=C:\Mesdocuments\controle.fmx
separateFrame=True
lookandfeel=Oracle
serverURL=/forms90/l90servlet
codebase=/forms90/java
imageBase=DocumentBase
width=800
height=600
splashScreen=no
background=no
lookAndFeel=Oracle
colorScheme=teal
logo=no
archive_jini=f90all_jinit.jar,FormsGraph.jar
archive_ie=f90all.cab
archive=f90all.jar
userid=ur2312/ur2312@base12
```

And i call this url: http:\10.112.98.168\forms90\f90servlet?config=Test.

But it doesn't work. Help me pleaaase!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these URLs:

http://10.112.98.168/forms/frmservlet?config=Test

or

http://10.112.98.168:8888/forms/frmservlet?config=Test

Also, check the port your OHS is running on - 80 or 8888

Comment: You can also try with port 7779, this is also used sometimes

Comment: I can't find OHS in my computer, am i supposed to install it? And which versiob?

Comment: Check out the WebLogic EM, it should show you if OHS is up (to begin with) and also the port it's running on. It's one of the OPMN processes installed together with the rest of the stack.